# How do you change the value inside of a textfield flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `TextEditingController` where if a user clicks a button it fills in with information. I can't seem to figure out how to change the text inside of a `Textfield` or `TextFormField`. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Simply change the `text` property

```
    TextField(
      controller: txt,
    ),
    RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
        txt.text = "My Stringt";
    }),
```

while `txt` is just a `TextEditingController`

```
  var txt = TextEditingController();
```

Comment: using this code the cursor goes to left of the Field. is there anyway o fix it?

Comment: @rickdroio Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57232719/6618622), it will put the cursor at the end.

Comment: @rickdroio yes, the comment down below https://stackoverflow.com/a/58307018/7691350

Comment: so I'll have to add a TextEditingController for each input I want to data bind?

Comment: The cursor position is set to -1 with this answer.

Answer (score 88):

The problem with just setting

```
_controller.text = "New value";
```

is that the cursor will be repositioned to the beginning (in material's TextField). Using

```
_controller.text = "Hello";
_controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
    TextPosition(offset: _controller.text.length),
);
setState(() {});
```

is not efficient since it rebuilds the widget more than it's necessary (when setting the text property and when calling setState).

--

I believe the best way is to combine everything into one simple command:

```
final _newValue = "New value";
_controller.value = TextEditingValue(
      text: _newValue,
      selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(offset: _newValue.length),
      ),
    );
```

It works properly for both Material and Cupertino Textfields.

Comment: This should be the right answer, since it deals with the problem of changing the controller's value and the cursor coming back to the start of the text all the time

Comment: One more suggestion, when providing offset, we can  do:
int currentOffset = _textEditingController.selection.base.offset;
And then provide currentOffset as offset. This will also handle the case when the user is in between the string.

Answer (score 61):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

1. Create a `TextEditingController`:

   ```dart
   final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
   ```
2. Assign it to your `TextField` or `TextFormField`:

   ```dart
   TextField(controller: _controller)
   ```
3. To update the text using a button at the *cursor position* (imagine there is already text in the textfield) :

   ```dart
   ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () {
       const newText = 'Hello World';
       final updatedText = _controller.text + newText;
       _controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(
         text: updatedText,
         selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: updatedText.length),
       );
     },
   )
   ```

Answer (score 31):

You can use the text editing controller to manipulate the value inside a textfield.

```
var textController = new TextEditingController();
```

Now, create a new textfield and set `textController` as the controller for the textfield as shown below.

```
 new TextField(controller: textController)
```

Now, create a `RaisedButton` anywhere in your code and set the desired text in the `onPressed` method of the `RaisedButton`.

```
new RaisedButton(
       onPressed: () {
          textController.text = "New text";
       }
    ),
```

Comment: There is no need to call setState on changing text of TextField

Answer (score 14):

```
_mytexteditingcontroller.value = new TextEditingController.fromValue(new TextEditingValue(text: "My String")).value;
```

This seems to work if anyone has a better way please feel free to let me know.

Comment: what about just : _mytexteditingcontroller.text= "your text"

Comment: Perfect if you want to create a TextField with a value already filled in :)

Answer (score 11):

First Thing

```
  TextEditingController MyController= new TextEditingController();
```

Then add it to init State or in any SetState

```
    MyController.value = TextEditingValue(text: "ANY TEXT");
```

Answer (score 9):

The issue does not appear if you use the `StatefulWidget` with `_controller` as a member. Sounds weird but moving from stateless to stateful worked fine (that's because the widget is redrawn on each input to text editing controller which does not preserve state) E.g.:

**Stateful:** (working)

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget(
      {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() =>
      _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState
    extends State<MyWidget> {
  late TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = TextEditingController(text: "My Text");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: _controller,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Stateless:** (issue)

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget(
      {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: TextEditingController(text: "My Text"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I love the solution for the stateless controller. So simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you simply want to replace the entire text inside the text editing controller, then the other answers here work. However, if you want to programmatically insert, replace a selection, or delete, then you need to have a little more code.

Making your own custom keyboard is one use case for this. All of the inserts and deletions below are done programmatically:

[image]

### Inserting text

The `_controller` here is a `TextEditingController` for the `TextField`.

```dart
void _insertText(String myText) {
  final text = _controller.text;
  final textSelection = _controller.selection;
  final newText = text.replaceRange(
    textSelection.start,
    textSelection.end,
    myText,
  );
  final myTextLength = myText.length;
  _controller.text = newText;
  _controller.selection = textSelection.copyWith(
    baseOffset: textSelection.start + myTextLength,
    extentOffset: textSelection.start + myTextLength,
  );
}
```

Thanks to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057840/flutter-how-to-insert-text-in-middle-of-text-field-text/60058972#60058972) for help with this.

### Deleting text

There are a few different situations to think about:

1. There is a selection (delete the selection)
2. The cursor is at the beginning (don’t do anything)
3. Anything else (delete the previous character)

Here is the implementation:

```dart
void _backspace() {
  final text = _controller.text;
  final textSelection = _controller.selection;
  final selectionLength = textSelection.end - textSelection.start;

  // There is a selection.
  if (selectionLength > 0) {
    final newText = text.replaceRange(
      textSelection.start,
      textSelection.end,
      '',
    );
    _controller.text = newText;
    _controller.selection = textSelection.copyWith(
      baseOffset: textSelection.start,
      extentOffset: textSelection.start,
    );
    return;
  }

  // The cursor is at the beginning.
  if (textSelection.start == 0) {
    return;
  }

  // Delete the previous character
  final newStart = textSelection.start - 1;
  final newEnd = textSelection.start;
  final newText = text.replaceRange(
    newStart,
    newEnd,
    '',
  );
  _controller.text = newText;
  _controller.selection = textSelection.copyWith(
    baseOffset: newStart,
    extentOffset: newStart,
  );
}
```

### Full code

You can find the full code and more explanation in my article [Custom In-App Keyboard in Flutter](https://suragch.medium.com/custom-in-app-keyboard-in-flutter-b925d56c8465).

Comment: I am using this code which is doing basically adding value at the start when value of textField is not null but problem is when it added $ sign after an input position of cursor changes and starts writing before value like if previous value was $1 then it writes 2$1. So is there any solution or better logic for this task?  " `onChanged: (value) {  if (dollarSignAdded == false) { 
 priceTextEditingController.value=TextEditingValue(  text: "\$" +priceTextEditingController.text);  dollarSignAdded = true;  }  else if (value.isEmpty) { 
 dollarSignAdded = false;  }  }`"

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare TextEditingController.
2. supply controller to the TextField.
3. user controller's text property to change the value of the textField.

follow this official [solution to the problem](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input)

Comment: What does this add to the solutions added before?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **full** example where the parent widget controls the children widget. The parent widget updates the children widgets (*Text* and *TextField*) with a counter.

To update the *Text* widget, all you do is pass in the *String* parameter.
To update the *TextField* widget, you need to pass in a controller, and set the text in the controller.

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Update Text and TextField demo'),
        ),
        body: ParentWidget());
  }
}

class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;
  String _text = 'no taps yet';
  var _controller = TextEditingController(text: 'initial value');

  void _handleTap() {
    setState(() {
      _counter = _counter + 1;
      _text = 'number of taps: ' + _counter.toString();
      _controller.text  = 'number of taps: ' + _counter.toString();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _handleTap,
          child: const Text('Tap me', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
        ),
        Text('$_text'),
        TextField(controller: _controller,),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply change the `text or value` property of controller.
if you do not edit selection property cursor goes to first of the new text.

```
onPress: () {
         _controller.value=TextEditingValue(text: "sample text",selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: sellPriceController.text.length)));                 
             }
```

or in case you change the .text property:

```
 onPress: () {
         _controller.text="sample text";
         _controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset:_controller.text.length));          
              }
```

in cases that do not matter to you just don't change the selection property

Answer (score 0):

simply add labelText to InputDecoration

```
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'init text'),
),
```

Answer (score -1):

add text to your controller like this image below

[image]