# Can I append a char/emoji with TextEditingController

Tags: flutter

I have a TextField like this:

```
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  ..
)
```

Where `_controller` is a `TextEditingController`. From outside my TextField. I have an emoji selector. When an emoji is selected, I want to append it to the controller's text, but there's no function like `_controller.addText(emoji)`. How can I insert something into the controller's text? Assuming there might be stuff typed before, or after I insert the emoji.

Comment: I have the same question as I was about to make the "PETER ANSWERS" project in a flutter. As the functionality I have to add the "Peter please answer" sentence after pressed the specific key like a "."

Answer (score 1):

_controller.text += emoji; should do it.

Comment: Hmm, that does work, thanks! However it resets the cursor to the beginning of the text. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: For more advanced workaround, you can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057840/flutter-how-to-insert-text-in-middle-of-text-field-text