# How can i send data to textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-form-builder

Hello i am reading a barcode and if the barcode reader i would like set up the input of the Textfield the the data that i read but i couldn't figured out how to do that here is my code

```
 TextField(
     textFieldData=readDataTurnString();
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {},
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Your Public Key'),

              ),
```

Comment: maybe this would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51127332/2281066

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are do something like following:

```
TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
    child: TextField(controller: _controller),
}
```

You can later use the **_controller** to set the value of **Textfield** like this:

```
_controller.text = "New Text Value";
```

Does this solve your problem?