# Flutter: How to insert text properly in a TextField/TextFormField

Tags: flutter, textfield, texteditingcontroller

Let's say there is an empty `TextFormField`. After entering 2 characters manually I would like to insert a new one programmatically. So if length equals with 2 than insert a new one. It sounds really simple but strange behaviors appeared while I tried to achieve this. For example: The cursor continuously jumps back to the start and may cause this debug log:

> Text selection index was clamped (-1->0) to remain in bounds. This may not be your fault, as some keyboards may select outside of bounds.

Or if I try to deal with the `TextEditingController`'s value or selection property to place cursor at the end of the text, it causes more strange behaviors.

Can you provide me an example by using a `TextField` or a `TextFormField` with a `TextEditingController` and on `onChanged()` if text length is equals with 2 than insert a new character at the end and place back the cursor also at the end.

I tried these solutions but in this case they did not work:
[How do you change the value inside of a textfield flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127241/how-do-you-change-the-value-inside-of-a-textfield-flutter/57232719#57232719)

Thank you!

EDIT: Example code:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'example',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(text: '');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (controller.text != null && controller.text.length == 2) {
          controller.text = '$value/';

          controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
              TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length));
          setState(() {});
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

}
```

**The problem: If I replace the TextFormField to a TextField, it works as expected.** I guess it is a bug that should be fixed.

I also found a link that in flutter version 1.20.1 and later this is an issue with TextFormFields.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62654

Comment: the link you provide is working fine. please post your reproduce code. thanks.

Comment: It's very strange because if I debug the process with a break point in my IDE it works fine but other than that it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

[TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) is a FormField that contains a TextField. While a [Form](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Form-class.html) isn't required to be its parent, using a Form makes it easier to manage multiple fields at once. You can stick with TextField if it works better and meets the requirements.