# How to limit user to enter more or less a particular value in TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a situation where I need to restrict users from entering a value greater than or less than a value (say `x` `<int>` type).

Here is my input field

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Amount',
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    enabled: widget.biller.paymentAmountExactness != 'EXACT',
  ),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
  controller: _amountFieldCtrl,
),
```

For understanding, let's consider the amount fetched from API is `400.00`. Now, I have a condition which is also, coming from API where I need to check `widget.biller.paymentAmountExactness` key. If the value key is `EXACT_UP` then, the user can enter the value in the `TextField` **400.00** or more.

Similarly, if the value is `EXACT_DOWN`, the user should not be able to enter the value in the field more than **400.00**.

I don't find any `max` or `min` parameter in the `TextField()` widget. How do I achieve such functionality?

Comment: Have you tried on changed? but i still couldn't get what u meant.

Comment: @Mahdi-Jafaree I very simple terms, I want to restrict the user to not able to enter a value in the input field which is greater than 400.00.

Comment: you can use either a TextFormField inside a form widget or the TextField with a error text below the text field. by textfield you can call setState (if u want a statefull widget) on every onChanged call and show your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a `TextEditingController`, then check for value change in the `TextField` using the `onChanged` parameter.
If you don't understand the `TextPosition` part you can [follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127241/how-do-you-change-the-value-inside-of-a-textfield-flutter), basically it's to avoid the cursor to jump to the start whenever you make a change.

Here is an example to what you want to achieve:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int min = 5;
  int max = 100;
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          controller: _textEditingController,
          onChanged: (String value) {
            print('Changed');
            int x;
            try {
              x = int.parse(value);
            } catch (error) {
              x = min;
            }
            if (x < min) {
              x = min;
            } else if (x > max) {
              x = max;
            }

            _textEditingController.value = TextEditingValue(
              text: x.toString(),
              selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
                TextPosition(offset: _textEditingController.value.selection.baseOffset),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**Note** that it would be a very poor design to handle this only like this. You should display an error message if you change the value automatically. To achieve this easily I would use a FormField, use form.validation at each step, and put the logic here.