# Update ListView when a details view changes state in Flutter App Skeleton

Tags: flutter

I have a very simple flutter app based on the default [Flutter Skeleton Application](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/29b7334290a3c654bf861c851bac3481491f80a8/packages/flutter_tools/templates/skeleton/lib/src/sample_feature/sample_item_list_view.dart.tmpl). It has a ListView called SampleItemListView, and it uses `Navigator.restorablePushNamed` to navigate to a SampleItemDetailsView when you click on an item in the list. The list view build method looks like this and is straight from the template:

ListView:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample Items'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.restorablePushNamed(context, SettingsView.routeName);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),

      body: ListView.builder(
        // Providing a restorationId allows the ListView to restore the
        // scroll position when a user leaves and returns to the app after it
        // has been killed while running in the background.
        restorationId: 'sampleItemListView',
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final item = items[index];

          return ListTile(
            title: Text('SampleItem ${item.id}'),
            leading: const CircleAvatar(
              // Display the Flutter Logo image asset.
              foregroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/flutter_logo.png'),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              // Navigate to the details page. If the user leaves and returns to
              // the app after it has been killed while running in the
              // background, the navigation stack is restored.
              Navigator.restorablePushNamed(
                context,
                SampleItemDetailsView.routeName,
              );
            }
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

DetailsView:

```dart
class MarkdownNodeDetailsView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MarkdownNodeDetailsView({super.key});

  static const routeName = '/markdown';

  @override
  State<MarkdownNodeDetailsView> createState() =>
      _MarkdownNodeDetailsViewState();
}

class _MarkdownNodeDetailsViewState extends State<MarkdownNodeDetailsView> {
  MarkdownNode? node;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
    if (args is Map && args['id'] != null) {
      findNodeById(int.parse(args['id']!)).then((value) {
        if (value != null) {
          setState(() {
            node = MarkdownNode(value.id!, value.properties['md']);
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      node = MarkdownNode(-1, '');
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    saveToRemoteDb();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var txtController = TextEditingController();
    var txt = node?.md ?? '';
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127241/how-do-you-change-the-value-inside-of-a-textfield-flutter
    txtController.value = TextEditingValue(
      text: txt,
      selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(offset: txt.length),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Item Details'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              child: TextField(
                controller: txtController,
                maxLines: null,
                expands: true,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(() {
                    node?.md = v;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My app introduces the ability to change the item from the details view. It works great on the details view, however, when the user pops back out to the list view, the list view does not reflect the updated state.

If I were instantiating SampleItemDetailsView directly I could pass a callback into it's constructor, but I'm not. It's being instantiated by the Navigator.

What is the proper way to notify the ListView that it may need an update when the detail view returns?

Comment: Can you include your details view page?

Comment: There are lots of state management options in flutter.
For this simple task, you can try to introduce a globalKey or for more compact solution you could check out [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).
Please add more code about your classes if you need more specific help.

Comment: Added the details view code

Answer (score 1):

So here is a sample using the provider package

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ItemProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<SampleItem> _items = [
    SampleItem(id: 1),
    SampleItem(id: 2),
    // Add more items as needed
  ];

  List<SampleItem> get items => _items;

  void updateItem(SampleItem item) {
    // Find the index of the item in the list
    int index = _items.indexWhere((element) => element.id == item.id);

    if (index != -1) {
      // Update the item in the list
      _items[index] = item;

      // Notify listeners that the state has changed
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}

class ItemsManager extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Items Manager'),
      ),
      body: Consumer<ItemProvider>(
        builder: (context, itemProvider, _) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: itemProvider.items.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final item = itemProvider.items[index];

              return ListTile(
                title: Text('SampleItem ${item.id} ${item.details}'),
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Icon(Icons.image),
                ),
                onTap: () async {
                  var result = await Navigator.restorablePushNamed(
                    context,
                    SampleItemDetailsView.routeName,
                  );

                  if (result != null && result is SampleItem) {
                    itemProvider.updateItem(result as SampleItem);
                  }
                },
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SampleItemDetailsView extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/sampleItemDetails';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final itemProvider = Provider.of<ItemProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample Item Details'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Details for SampleItem'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Update the details of the first item
                SampleItem updatedItem = SampleItem(
                  id: itemProvider.items.first.id,
                  details: 'Updated details',
                );

                // Notify listeners and pop this view off the navigation stack
                itemProvider.updateItem(updatedItem);

                Navigator.pop(context, updatedItem);
              },
              child: Text('Update Item Details'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SampleItem {
  final int id;
  String details;

  SampleItem({required this.id, this.details = 'Initial details'});
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ItemProvider(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ItemsManager(),
      routes: {
        SampleItemDetailsView.routeName: (context) => SampleItemDetailsView(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: add   provider: ^6.1.1 to your pubspec.yaml dependencies